# VIdeo playback not working on samsung tv

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

I created a sample application using samsung tv sdk and added video player with the bellow code.but it does not playing my video

```
SceneScene1.prototype.initialize = function () {
    alert("SceneScene1.initialize()");
    // this function will be called only once when the scene manager show this scene first time
    // initialize the scene controls and styles, and initialize your variables here
    // scene HTML and CSS will be loaded before this function is called
    sf.service.VideoPlayer.init({
        onend:function(){
            sf.service.VideoPlayer.setFullScreen(false);
        }
    });
    sf.service.VideoPlayer.setKeyHandler(sf.key.RETURN, 
    function(){
        sf.service.VideoPlayer.setFullScreen(false);
    });
    var vLeft = parseInt($("#svecVideo_y5ww").css('left'));
    var vTop = parseInt($("#svecVideo_y5ww").css('top'));
    var vHeight = parseInt($("#svecVideo_y5ww").css('height'));
    var vWidth = parseInt($("#svecVideo_y5ww").css('width'));
    sf.service.VideoPlayer.setPosition({
        left:vLeft,
        top:vTop,
        width:vWidth,
        height:vHeight
    });
    sf.service.VideoPlayer.show();
    sf.service.VideoPlayer.play({
        url: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
        fullScreen: false,
        title: 'Samsung movie',
        startTime: 5,
        liveStream: false,
        timeString: true,
        authHeader: 'none'
    });

};
```

and if we try to inspect using web inspector.it shows the bellow errors

> Service is unavailable due to network or service interference.
>
> The file can't be played because the format isn't supported.
>
> Unable to play the file. Please check it and try again later.

i tried with different files,and shows the same error

Comment: @Surreal here i got the code from http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/API00005/sf.service.VideoPlayer_42

Comment: yeah I just saw that, do you think `This class will not be supported in 2015.` may be effecting this?

Comment: But my device UBD-K8500 is using 2016